# In real estate, what is a split plan?

Tags: meaning, nouns, terminology

I'm looking through house listings and keep coming across "split plan." This is not a synonym of "split level," because the houses are pretty flat. What is a "split plan" house?

Comment: I assume this is an American term? I don't think I've heard it in the UK.

Comment: I hadn't heard it before either, but it appears to refer to homes with the master bedroom separated from the other bedrooms: http://wiki.answers.com/Q/What_is_a_split_floor_plan

Answer (score 3, accepted):

***[Split Plan](http://wiki.answers.com/Q/What_is_a_split_floor_plan)***: The master bedroom is on one side of the home away from the other bedrooms, located on the opposite side, thus offering more privacy for the master bedroom.